# Stop getting data from arduino when python get data from it

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am doing Python and Arduino serial communication. This is part of my code.

```
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()
    str = data[:-2].decode()
    print(str) # to check the str

    if str: # if str gets 1 from arduino
        some logics here..............
```

but the problem is when python code is running that while clause, Arduino is still sending data to Python. I think if it keep send it to python, I don't think that code goes well. So the question is how to stop sending data when while clause is started? Thank you in advance.

The whole codes are here just right here!

python code

```
import serial
import time
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime
import cv2
import boto3
now = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
station="hansung-"
type=".jpg"
filename=station+now+type

st=filename.split('-')[0]
ye=filename.split('-')[1]
mo=filename.split('-')[2]
da=filename.split('-')[3]



#the picture is just uploaded in to s3 bucket


port ="COM15" #I am testing this on my windows laptop
brate = 9600
arduino =serial.Serial(port, baudrate = brate, timeout=None)


while True:
    #keep receive data from arduino
    data= arduino.readline()
    # delete \n\r from arduino
    str = data[:-2].decode()
    # if person exists str = 1 or str = 0
    print(str)
    if str:
        #if picture is taken
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
        cap.release()
        print('picture is taken')

        #upload in to s3
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucketname = 'dongyeon2'
        bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)
        bucket.upload_file(filename, filename, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public- read'})
        bucketurl = "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/dongyeon2/"     +     filename


        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='', db='pythonprogramming')
        cur = db.cursor()

        #insert into sql
        sql = "insert into image(station,year,month,day,img_url) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cur.execute(sql, (st, ye, mo, da, bucketurl))


        db.commit()
        db.close()

    else:
      print("no body")
```

This is Arduino code

```
int IR_sensor = A0;
int value;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(IR_sensor, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  long IR_value = analogRead(IR_sensor);
  long IR_range = gp2y0a21yk(IR_value);


  if(IR_range < 50)
  {
    value=1;
    Serial.println(value);
  }
  else {
    value=0;
    Serial.println(value);
  }
  delay(1000);
}

long gp2y0a21yk(long IR_value)
{
  if (IR_value < 10)
  {
    IR_value = 10;
  }

  return ((67870.0 / (IR_value-3.0)) - 40.0)/10;
}
```

What I am trying to do is when the person pass the some point and then str is changed to 1 and then take picture the person and then upload to s3 and also save it to the sql. If there is no person just print out no body. But right now I face the problem that it doesn't work what I hope. it only shows up 
0
no body
0
no body

So I think this is happened because the Arduino is keep send data to python and python reads the str value and go to while clause before the previous one has done. Thakn you sir

Comment: Maybe expand your code to show the arduino object, etc. :) Does the if stop the while loop? What are you trying to achieve (use case)?

Comment: @Roelant Thx sir!! Wait for a second!

Comment: @Roelant I did it. Thank you

Comment: Did you test if the arduino ever returns 1? I think your theory doesn't work: after reading one line, it must enter the if before reading one again :)

Comment: @Roelant no I didn't ..... So do I have to test when arduino returns 1??

Comment: @Roelant Yeah it might enter if but if 0 is coming it goes to else so it can print out 0 and no body. It is just my theory...

Comment: I would start doing a simple test to prove that arduino actually returns 1 when the sensor is activated :)

Comment: @Roelant that's the best way.... I will upload later when I do that thank you for saving my life. You are my hero!

Comment: @Roelant Thank you sir!! I almost have solved it by testing sending fixed value!!!